# How to display HTML local storage link within modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I have a modal that displays API images within a modal, and I want the "Add To Favourites" link to be shown within the modal.
So far, I can display the "title", "explanation" and "date" by using result.title etc.
However when I use result.saveText to display the "add to favourites" as a HTML link is display undefined.
How do I display the "Add To Favourites as an HTML link within the modal?

```
// Image
const image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = result.url;
image.alt = result.title + "<br>" + result.explanation + "<br>" + result.date;
image.loading = "lazy";
image.classList.add("card-img-top");

// Card Title
const cardTitle = document.createElement("h5");
cardTitle.classList.add("card-title");
cardTitle.textContent = result.title;

// Save Text
const saveText = document.createElement("p");
saveText.classList.add("clickable");
if (page === "results") {
  saveText.textContent = "Add To Favorites";
  saveText.setAttribute("onclick", `saveFavorite('${result.url}')`);
} else {
  saveText.textContent = "Remove Favorite";
  saveText.setAttribute("onclick", `removeFavorite('${result.url}')`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code showing (except not appending it either to a parent element or document.body)

I check your model and I found that the `saveText` doesn't append to any parent element or any document.body. The element of your code doesn't even has `p` tag.

Your probably should use `append` method to append it to either a parent element or a child element. In your situation, you probably should use `cardTitle.appendChild(SaveText)`

Doesn't even has `p` tag in your whole `body`:

[image]

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img')[1].onerror = function(){
let div = document.createElement('div')
div.textContent = 'Link is invalid.'
document.body.appendChild(div)
}
```

```html
<img src="invalid.jpg" alt ="<a href='https://www.w3schools.com'>Visit W3Schools.com!</a>">
<img src="invalid.jpg" >
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for answering the question. Newbie question, but I am wondering how do I include a button or link text within the modal to the code: 

image.alt = result.title + "<br>" + result.explanation + "<br>" + result.date;

Comment: Example - To include the title its result.title - to include the explanation its result.explanation - but how do include the "Add To Favorites" code as a link? Thanks

Comment: @user8, I don't think you could put html tag in img `alt` mdn states that alt `Defines an alternative text description of the image.` So i good option is to use `img.onerror` in the code I updated. Check it. Also, I see you want to include the `add To favorites code as a link`, maybe just define it as an `a` tag and assign it an onclick function